# MS SQL view to a DB2 query

Tags: sql-server, db2

How can I join a MS SQL view to a DB2 query?

I have done it on a MS SQL Server but the time is to long (3 Minutes for 160 rows) because I have to open 8 query’s to get my results.
So know I am searching for another result to get what I want.

Thanks

Comment: `I have done it on a MS SQL Server but the time is to long (3 Minutes for 160 rows) because I have to open 8 query’s to get my results. So know I am searching for another result to get what I want.` please elaborate this as much as possible with examples

Comment: Even if you create a view by using openquery in SQL Server, a view has no data. Getting data locally vs fetching the data far away/remotely, which way may faster?

Comment: select * from deliver is my MS SQL query what I want to import into my DB2 query
select * from tabA a join tabB b on a.id = b.id.... and this over 8 tables
what I now want is to have a query like this:
select * from tabA a join tabB b on a.id = b.id ... join deliver s on s.shipper = a.shipper
I always done it on MS SQL with a linked server and openquery but it was to slow...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a linked server and OPENQUERY.

Comment: but it is to slow

Comment: Then you are not asking the right question.   You asked, "How can I join a MS SQL view to a DB2 query?"

Comment: Sorry I was thinking you mean in MS SQL this way is to slow